# Jest - why embedded mocked functions must have a ref for jest tests

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mocking

So i have a `firebase.js` file,

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';

const auth = firebase.auth();

export const watchUserAuthState = cb => auth.onAuthStateChanged(cb);
```

and i want to write unit tests for it in my `firebase.test.js` file

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';

jest.mock('firebase/app');
const firebase = jest.createMockFromModule('firebase/app');
const mockAuth = jest.fn(() => ({
    onAuthStateChanged: jest.fn(),
        }
}));
firebase.auth = mockAuth;

describe('watchUserAuthState', () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
            jest.clearAllMocks();
        });
        it('should call Firebase auth.onAuthStateChanged', () => {
            const callback = jest.fn();
            watchUserAuthState(callback);
            expect(firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        });
    });
```

This test doesn't work unless I switch this line :
`const mockAuth = jest.fn(() => ({ onAuthStateChanged: jest.fn(), } }));`
by this :
`const mockOnAuthStateChanged = jest.fn(); const mockAuth = jest.fn(() => ({ onAuthStateChanged: mockOnAuthStateChanged, } }));`
Can someone explain to me why this is necessary ?